# Checking network status and controlling PPP in a program

Tags: c, linux, networking, embedded, ppp

So I'm running PPP under linux with a cellular modem.  The program I'm writing needs to know if the link is active before sending any data.

What are my options to check

- if the link is available
- if it routes to a server I control (it doesn't go to the internet as I said earlier)

Also, what is the best way to restart it - I'd like to have program control over when it starts and stops, so I assume an init.d isn't appropriate.  Using `system()` doesn't seem to give a PID, are there other options besides `fork()` and the gaggle of `exec??()` calls?

C on Linux on ARM (custom distribution using buildroot).

Comment: @Adam: Rep recalc complete.  Sorry for you loss. :(

Comment: Oh hey, thanks, the loss was minimal.  I honestly thought it'd be much greater with all the stuff that's been migrated over time.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use the `ip-up` script functionality of pppd to have it execute a program when the IP interface is up and ready. Details are in the [pppd(8) man page](http://ppp.samba.org/pppd.html) - search for "ip-up".

To restart pppd, use the `linkname` parameter to set a known pidfile name (`/var/run/ppp-name.pid`). Also use the `persist` option. When you want to restart pppd, send the `SIGHUP` signal. Again, this is described in the man page.

Answer (score 3):

You could parse `/proc/net/route`.